# Filter that exists in Tomcat doesn't in Jetty, how do I get Jetty to ignore it?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jetty

We have a project that we run in both Tomcat and Jetty. I have added a filter in my web.xml:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

The CorsFilter class is shipped with Tomcat, but Jetty doesn't find it (and thus doesn't start).

Is there any way I can get Jetty to ignore this declaration? Or make it only apply to Tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution is to remove it from web.xml. This is the deployment descriptor after all, which exists precisely to customize the deployment of the app.

If you really want to have a single war file deployable on both servers without being touched, then you could write your own filter that delegates to the catalina CorsFilter is available, and doesn't do anything if not available.

You would test if the filter is available by doing `Class.forName("org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter")` and see if you get an exception.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much what I ended up doing, I removed it where it was, and put it in Tomcats global web.xml, via our deployment procedure. This setting might as well be global in our case.